# Time save in db in magento2?

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

I 'm able to get gmtDate.But,I can't not save that in db.How to save gmt time in database?

```
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context;

class Faq extends AbstractDb
{

    /**
     * Date model
     * 
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime
     */
    protected $_date;

    /**
     * constructor
     * 
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(DateTime $date, Context $context)
    {
        $this->_date = $date;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Define main table
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('faqs', 'id');
    }

    protected function _beforeSave(\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $object)
    {
        $object->setUpdatedAt($this->_date->gmtDate());
        if ($object->isObjectNew()) {
            $object->setCreatedAt($this->_date->gmtDate());
        }
        return parent::_beforeSave($object);
    }
```

If anyone knows please explain me?